# Define ActiveRecord connection for given Resque queue

Tags: activerecord, heroku, resque

### Problem Domain

Heroku Cedar stack, with multiple databases. RDS for main database, and Postgres for a second Analytics database. Server runs using the read/write RDS *and* Postgres databases. Nightly rake task, which are run in a different environment, needs to run a specific Resque queue in a read-only slave of the RDS database.

### Postgres DB connection

For the record, all models in the Postgres database include:

```
module Trove::PostgresConnection
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      …set up Postgres database
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine, and, being a module injected into each class, does not get squashed by any changes to ActiveRecord::Base.connection

### MySQL Connection

Defined using the Heroku RDS plugin. Connection is made to the read/write production database. Unfortunately, *this connection is used regardless of environment*. Thus, running a rake task on Heroku using `RAILS_ENV=analytics rake some:task` does not use this connection for `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
analytics:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dbase
  username: uname
  password: pword
  host: read-only.uri.on.amazonaws.com
  reconnect: true
  port: 3306
```

Rather, it uses the connection string provided in the RDS connection:

```
puts Rails.env
-> 'analytics'
puts SomeModel.connection_config[:host]
-> read-write.uri.on.amazonaws.com
```

Took me a while to figure that out. Note to self: don't just look at environment, look at database host.

### Current Workaround

```
# Perform an operation using another database connection in ActiveRecord
module SwapConnection

  def with_connection_to(config, &block)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)

    yield

  end
end

require 'swap_connection'
class TroveCalculations
  @queue = :trove_queue

  def self.perform(class_name, id)
    SwapConnection.with_connection_to(Rails.env) do
      Do something in a given queue
    end
  end
end
```

### Desired ability

Have something like this in the Procfile

```
troveworker:    env RAILS_ENV=analytics QUEUE=trove_queue bundle exec rake resque:work
```

which *actually uses the analytics database.yml config for that worker*. We currently run our server with this Procfile, but it still uses the RDS database.

Comment: Shot in the dark... your app is getting the RDS config from environment variables (yay Heroku!), could you use a different value that way?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. My point is that I don't want to change this on a per-job basis when 400k jobs get thrown into the queue. I want to be able to say "For this entire queue, use this database string for all workers." I don't seem to be able to.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment on the question, I meant adding a config for your DB the "Heroku way" and then referencing it in your Procfile for the one worker that will process jobs on that queue.

Add a config/environment variable with the DB config you need using a new name:

```
heroku config:add ANALYTICS_DB=postgres://some_url
```

And in your `Procfile`, based on your example of what you want:

```
troveworker:    env DATABASE_URL=$(ANALYTICS_DB) QUEUE=trove_queue \
                bundle exec rake resque:work
```

You'll have to use separate workers for each queue with a different config this way, but the config will be out of the code at least.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I was assuming that this would get clobbered by the global config, but I haven't actually tried it. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

I've only played with Heroku, but I thought the database connection info was overridden by the Heroku tools based on environment variables specified by the heroku toolbelt.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is Heroku generates its own database.yml file: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior

By using the Amazon RDS addon, Heroku sets a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. You can see its contents by running the following from the root of your applications directory:
`heroku config`

Also, as of Rails 3.2, it will use a `DATABASE_URL` env var (if set) instead of a database.yml file:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/503#issuecomment-11862427

The simplest workaround might be to:

1. create an env var called `DATABASE_URL_ANALYTICS` w/ the Postgres connection string:
   `heroku config:add DATABASE_URL_ANALYTICS=postgres://xxxxxxxxxxxx`
2. At the beginning of your rake file (before any rails initialization might occur), add:
   `ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = ENV['DATABASE_URL_ANALYTICS'] if Rails.env.analytics?`

Comment: Our rake task starts multiple jobs, some read-only, some write. The environment of the rake file doesn't affect the environment of the Resque job since they are forked in their own Rails initialization. We effectively do this explicit connection definition on a per job basis, but it would be much better on a per queue basis so we don't have to switch for *every* read-only job.

Answer (score 0):

### Update: Not working. (original answer kept for documentation)

This is how we've solved it:

Procfile:

```
troveworker:    env RAILS_ENV=analytics QUEUE=trove_queue rake trove:worker
```

lib/tasks/trove.rake:

```
desc 'Start the Resque workers in the proper environment'
task :worker do
  SwapConnection.with_connection_to Rails.env do
    Rake::Task['resque:work'].invoke
  end
end
```

This solution solves some other issues for us as well, and works quite nicely. Thanks everyone.